# Load custom font file from application specific folder

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, win32gui

My Win32 application has to load a custom font file from ProgramFiles folder. 
Is it possible to load a custom font file from custom location?
If so how can I load a custom font file?

Please suggest.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [AddFontResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183326.aspx) or [AddFontResourceEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183327.aspx)

Note:

> When an application no longer needs a font resource that it loaded by
>   calling the AddFontResource function, it must remove that resource by
>   calling the RemoveFontResource function. This function installs the
>   font only for the current session. When the system restarts, the font
>   will not be present. To have the font installed even after restarting
>   the system, the font must be listed in the registry.

Comment: @ manuell sorry for my very late replay.. Yes it works fine. Thank you.